# Linux : How to forward a program window from my laptop to my desktop securely?

Tags: linux, ssh, x-windows

Can't I forward a program window from my laptop to my desktop securely, both running Linux?

How to ssh -X an existing window program just like the 'screen' program does?

This question came up with my friends when watching an episode of 24! "Almeida send me your screen"

Comment: I didn't see the episode, but might just a picture of the screen been forwarded? i.e. `ssh -X you@desktop xwd -root >~/screen.xwd`?

Comment: @DaveParillo: hehe, nice hack. nevertheless a "not so effective" screenshoter (thats why rdp + vnc where developed).

Comment: Nice hack I agree!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [XVnc](http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/) and then use any vnc-client to "watch what can be watched on the xvnc server".

Comment: I think vnc is the way to go.  If you wanted to login & run the program yourself, it would be easy to `ssh -X` & run your program.  Not sure there is a secure way to connect to a program that is already running and redirect it's display to you.  I would recommend tightVNC over xvnc, however: http://www.tightvnc.com/.

Comment: secure: tunnel vnc through ssh. tightvnc is windows only, iirc.

Comment: Why this functionnality is not developed yet? Technically difficult to implement ? Or the need for that is not there? I reward you with the reponse accepted because it seems that there is no alternative besides vnc.